# I get following error in anaconda prompt and can not open navigator or jupyter notebook or anything related anaconda

Tags: anaconda, anaconda3

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\V\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 16, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\V\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 66, in main_subshell
    from .conda_argparse import generate_parser
  File "C:\Users\V\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 31, in <module>
    from ..base.context import context
  File "C:\Users\V\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ..common._os.linux import linux_get_libc_version
  File "C:\Users\V\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\_os\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .windows import get_free_space_on_windows as get_free_space
  File "C:\Users\V\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\_os\windows.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ctypes import (
  File "C:\Users\V\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\V\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\V\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 129, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(main, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\V\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 376, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\V\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 19, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\V\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 51, in handle_exception
    from .exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\V\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .models.channel import Channel
  File "C:\Users\V\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\models\channel.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ..base.context import Context, context
  File "C:\Users\V\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 28, in <module>
    from ..common._os.linux import linux_get_libc_version
  File "C:\Users\V\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\_os\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .windows import get_free_space_on_windows as get_free_space
  File "C:\Users\V\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\_os\windows.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ctypes import (
  File "C:\Users\V\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes: The specified module could not be found.
PS C:\Users\V>
```

Comment: From your prompt `PS C:\Users\V>` it doesn't look like `base` is properly activated. Are you running this from `anaconda` powershell prompt`

Comment: Yes I tried in both prompt and powershell prompt but can not change to base - all conda commands fail

Comment: Then that is the issue you need to adress. What error messages do you get when you start `anaconda prompt`? Have you manually changed anything like `PATH` or moved the anaconda folder to a different location?

Comment: No I have not changed any path - when I open prompt or powershell prompt - I get the same errors I mentioned in original post. even with cmd I get the same error. This happened after I tried updating anaconda using conda - is there any way to save multiple jupyter notebook files I have created - if yes I have no problem uninstall and reinstall

Comment: the jupyter notebook files that you have created are perfectly fine. Think of it like reinstalling microsoft word. All `.docx` that you have on your drive will not be deleted just because you are uninstalling office. Is the same with anaconda.

Comment: I am assuming that you have saved these files somewhere other than C:\Users\V\anaconda3

Comment: This all happened when I had a mismatch between actual python version which is 3.11.4 and anaconda was showing 3.10.9 -- I used conda forge - dont remember exact command - those Jupyter notebooks are saved in V folder and not under V\anaconda3 --- I wish there was a way to fix this without uninstalling - and should I go for clean uninstall or just remove that anaconda3 folder?

Comment: In case you want to fix, I would start with the error messages that you get when you run any `conda` command in your command prompt. One can maybe start from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254142/discussion-between-flyingteller-and-hellov).